# Flash downloader for linux firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, download-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Youtube and Google video downloaders ?](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders)

Do you know any ?
I mean something which could allow me for example to download yt movies.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006/) add-on for Firefox

Comment: +1 Downloading the flash itself (which you can find in "Page Info" or Ctrl+I) would just give you the player without the movie.

Answer (score 0):

use the Synaptic Package Manager to intstall "flashplugin-installer"